# How to uninstall programs in Ubuntu Mate 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu-mate, software-uninstall

I want to uninstall some programs in Ubuntu Mate 16.04.

I have searched for answers but they often say "use Synaptic" or "use the Software Centre" but I don't have either of these. I only have - rather confusingly I might add - Software Boutique, Software Updater, and Software & Updates.

Sometimes they also say "right click the program from the menu" but that doesn't give an uninstall option. I just want to see a list of installed programs and click "uninstall" or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

You can use command line and introduce these commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove <program name>
sudo apt-get purge <program name>
```

First (`apt-get remove`) will remove program, but save its configuration files (usually in /etc); but the second (`apt-get purge`) will remove program with its configuration files.

Comment: I don't want to learn computer code, I just want something simple like uninstall programs in Windows. Is there anything like that?

Comment: Aptitude just can do the work, install it

Comment: Okay, so just I'm clear, I have to install another program called Aptitude to uninstall programs? There is nothing in Ubuntu Mate already that can do this?

Comment: Yes, you have to install it

Comment: Ok, well it doesn't exist in Software Boutique, but thanks.

Comment: What? @Bluesun aptitude is similar to APT, which is what this answer suggests using. APT is already installed. There is no need to install Aptitude.

Answer (score 1):

`Aptitude` is a nice text based package manager that will resolve dependencies. It lists installed, not installed, upgradeable, etc. Among other features, it has a search and dependency resolver.

If you don't have it open a terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

It can be issued command via command line, but to launch the interface open a terminal and run:

```
sudo aptitude
```

Comment: I have no idea what resolve dependencies means. I just want to uninstall Opera and Redshift. Is there not a simple Uninstall button somewhere? Are you saying I have to install something to uninstall programs?

Comment: in the package managers.  or via command. open a terminal and type: `sudo apt-get remove opera redshift`

Comment: the last line of my question:  "I just want to see a list of installed programs and click "uninstall" or something similar. Thanks." Is this not possible in Ubuntu Mate?

Comment: Okay I searched for Aptitude in Software Boutique and it says "no software matches your keywords".

Comment: there are several, I prefer using aptitude. you should also have synaptic package manager already installed. I'm not familiar with software boutique but that may also be a package manager.

Comment: Ok so do you actually use Ubuntu Mate? Because Software Boutique is in Ubuntu Mate. And no there is no Synaptic installed.

Comment: I use Mate desktop, installed on ubuntu.

Comment: Mate 16.04? I'm just confused as to why people are telling me to use things that aren't included in my version of Linux. And I had no idea a simple thing like uninstalling a browser would be such a nightmare, I'm being told to install 'Aptitude' which doesn't exist in the Software Boutique.

Comment: Mate 1.16 on ubuntu 16.04.  did you select a package manager from your welcome menu?  https://www.pscp.tv/qwertyuiop____5678/1YqKDLjnpjaKV

Comment: When I click 'Software' on the welcome menu it just says 'Stocking the boutique'

Comment: https://ubuntu-mate.community/uploads/default/original/2X/9/92775020ed31bdebaf407f0e96949a4a4f3fb946.png

Comment: Mine looks nothing like that: https://s17.postimg.org/xa5iuaji7/Screenshot_at_2017-11-29_10_18_16.png

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS as in other Ubuntu flavors you can install the following software managers:

- Synaptic (`sudo apt-get install synaptic apt-xapian-index`);
- Muon (`sudo apt-get install muon`);
- Ubuntu Software Center (`sudo apt-get install software-center`);
- Aptitude (`sudo apt-get install aptitude`).

All these programs allow to search, list, install and uninstall (like `appwiz.cpl` in MS Windows) programs.

After long [result-less discussion on the mailing list](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-desktop/2017-August/005156.html) my favorite for daily use is Muon.

When I have serious problems I use `aptitude`.

Answer (score 0):

In at least 18.04 LTS, it is possible to uninstall software without going through the terminal.

Using the software boutique, you can install synaptic. Use the search option. Install synaptic and use that to uninstall software.

Answer (score 0):

I came through same problem. Just install 'Synaptic' or  'Software' Application from Software Boutique. Its very handy.